# R How to apply function to several subsets

Tags: r, apply, subset

My dataset looks something like this:

```
movie.id unknown Action Adventure rating 
1        0       0      0         3.831461 
2        0       1      1         3.416667 
3        0       0      0         3.945946
4        0       1      0         2.894737
5        1       0      0         4.358491
```

I would like to compute mean rating of every genre. I can subset every one by hand, but I would like to do it more automatically

update1: every movie can have more than one genre, for every genre there is column with value 1 if movie is in the genre or 0 if is not

update2: so I would like to compute mean of ratings for every movie that have 1 in adventure column, and next for every movie that have 1 in action column, and unknown column (unknown is also genre) and so on

Comment: What defines a "Genre"? Can films be more than one genre? Movie 2 is Action and Adventure genres or is movie 2 the "Action-Adventure" genre?

Comment: action and adventure are two genres, every movie van be in more than one genre

Comment: Or in no genres? (movie 1 and 3 above)?

Comment: in that case it will be probably unknown, I don't know if there is movie without genre. There are more genres in dataset, I just copied a few of then, so probably not

Answer (score 1):

I believe this looks valid, too:

```
genres = names(DF)[2:4]
ret = lapply(genres, function(x) mean(DF[["rating"]][as.logical(DF[[x]])]))
cbind.data.frame(genres, means = unlist(ret)) #or whatever formating manipulation
#     genres    means
#1   unknown 4.358491
#2    Action 3.155702
#3 Adventure 3.416667
```

Where `DF`:

```
DF = structure(list(movie.id = 1:5, unknown = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
), Action = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Adventure = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), rating = c(3.831461, 3.416667, 3.945946, 2.894737, 4.358491
)), .Names = c("movie.id", "unknown", "Action", "Adventure", 
"rating"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reshape2` and `dplyr` packages:

First install them:

```
> install.packages("reshape2")
> install.packages("dplyr")
> require(reshape2)
> require(dplyr)
```

then:

```
> m
  id unknown Action Adventure     rating
1  1       0      0         0 0.51391395
2  2       0      1         1 0.02915435
3  3       0      0         0 0.88752693
4  4       0      1         0 0.57660751
5  5       1      0         0 0.59169393
```

then its a one-liner:

```
> melt(m,measure=c("Action","Adventure","unknown")) %.% filter(value==1) %.% group_by(variable) %.% summarize(meanRating = mean(rating))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

   variable meanRating
1    Action 0.30288093
2 Adventure 0.02915435
3   unknown 0.59169393
```

Just to check, the only non-trivial one is:

```
> mean(m$rating[m$Action==1])
[1] 0.3028809
```

Set the `measure=` parameter to the names of your genre columns when you have lots of genres.

Change the name of the variable to get something a bit nicer:

```
> melt(m,measure=c("Action","Adventure","unknown"),variable.name="genre") %.% filter(value==1) %.% group_by(genre) %.% summarize(meanRating = mean(rating))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

      genre meanRating
1    Action 0.30288093
2 Adventure 0.02915435
3   unknown 0.59169393
```

Comment: it looks that it would produce output i want but I get this error: Error: could not find function "%.%" What does it mean? How can I use it?